# How to express the following meaning using a single exclamatory sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, exclamatives

I betrayed someone in the past. Now I regret and I blame myself for my betrayal.
I want to use a single exclamatory sentence to express self-blame, starting by 'how'.
I guess it may be: 'How shall I betray him!'.
Am I correct?

Comment: 'How shall I betray him' is a question. An exclamation would more typically be, 'How I have betrayed him!' It sounds rather archaic though.

Comment: Also, "How shall I betray him" sounds as if you are planning to do it in the future. "I really failed him!" or "I really let him down!" are probably what I'd say, but they don't start with "how". "How could I be so disloyal?" maybe.

Comment: This is an odd thing to ask and we really need more details.  What is the context? Who are you speaking to? In speech or on paper? Why do you need to express self-blame? What was the nature of the betrayal? Why do you need to start the sentence with "How"? Are you writing poetry? Is this for real or for a fictional character?  It is such an unusual request that there needs to be a lot of context.